# lerna publish not working in GitHub Actions

Tags: github-actions, lerna, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

We have a monorepo that we are using Lerna to publish to a private package manager (nexus). When the action runs, it fails with same vague message:

```
info cli using local version of lerna
lerna notice cli v5.3.0
lerna info ci enabled
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

This message occurs after github actions tries to run the `lerna publish` command.

I've tried dozens of variations of installing Lerna globally and locally as well as all sort of variations of flags on my `lerna bootstrap` and `lerna publish` commands. I am not sure what to try. Any insights would be appreciated. Below is my worklflow file.

Node: 16.15.1
Lerna: 5.3.0

**release.yml**

```
name: 'MyPackage Production Release'

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      version:
        required: true
        type: choice
        description: Which version should be published?
        options:
          - patch
          - minor
          - major
      tag:
        required: true
        type: choice
        description: Which npm tag should this be published to?
        options:
          - latest
          - next
          - test

jobs:
  build-my-package:
    runs-on: [self-hosted, Linux, X64, enterprise]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0 #indicates all history for all branches and tags.
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 16.15.1
          registry-url: 'https://registry.npmjs.org'
      - name: Configure Identity
        run: |
          git config user.name github-actions
          git config user.email github-actions@github.com
        shell: bash
      - name: strict SSL
        run: |
          npm config set cafile my-file.pem
          npm config set strict-ssl false
          npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.our.proxysite.net:80/
          npm config set proxy http://proxy.our.proxysite.net:80/
          npm config set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0
          npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: |
          npm ci --no-package-lock --legacy-peer-deps
          lerna bootstrap --ignore-scripts -- --legacy-peer-deps
        shell: bash
      - name: Prepare Nexus Token
        run: |
          npm config set registry https://nexus.our.site.net/repository/my-package-repo/
          npm config set email myemail@myemail.net
          npm config set strictSSL false
          npm config set alwaysAuth true
          echo //nexus.our.site.net/repository/my-package-repo/:_auth=${{ secrets.NEXUS_BASE64_AUTH }} > .npmrc
          npm config set _auth ${{ secrets.NEXUS_BASE64_AUTH }}
        shell: bash
      - name: Release
        run: |
          HUSKY_SKIP_HOOKS=1 lerna publish $(echo "${{ github.event.inputs.version }}") --yes --force-publish='*' --dist-tag $(echo "${{ github.event.inputs.tag }}") --conventional-commits --create-release github
        env:
          GH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GH_TOKEN }}
          GHE_API_URL: ${{ secrets.GHE_API_URL }}
          GHE_VERSION: ${{ secrets.GHE_VERSION }}
        shell: bash
```

Comment: Try running lerna with `--loglevel silly`